# Font of all the controls in VBA Userform using For loop

Tags: vba, excel, fonts, controls, userform

[The sample userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi2W4.jpg)

All I want is, when I press a button, the font of all the controls is changed to a desired value. I wrote this for a `commandbutton`like below and it works fine for it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
CommandButton2.Font = "Arial"
End Sub
```

This works fine. But when I try to use the for loop for the same application, I get error. The snippet in which I get error is

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim x As Control
CommandButton2.Font = "Arial"
For Each x In Me.Controls
    x.Font = "Arial"
Next
End Sub
```

The error:

> '438: Object doesn't support this property or method'.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check what `Me` refers to in this context

Comment: That should be: `x.Font.Name = "Arial"`

Comment: What other type of controls are on the form? Not all controls have a Font property. You may want to include a check for the type of control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can be sure that all the controls have a Font property, then simply change `x.Font = "Arial"` to `x.Font.Name = "Arial"`

If you have Images, ScrollBars, Spinbuttons or other controls that don't have Font, you could filter them out with an IF statment:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim x As Control
CommandButton2.Font = "Arial"
For Each x In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(x) <> "Image" And TypeName(x) <> "SpinButton" And TypeName(x).... Then
        x.Font.Name = "Arial"
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Or you could use the lesser advised `On Error Resume Next`..

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim x As Control
CommandButton2.Font = "Arial"
On Error Resume Next
For Each x In Me.Controls
    x.Font.Name = "Arial"
Next
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```